# Multi line comment issue in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code block will not accept a multi line comment for the whole block using `"""` - I suspect this is because three double quotes have been used for a string to span multiple lines as part of this code block.

```
"""

tabby_cat = "\tI'm tabbed in."
persian_cat = "I'm split\non a line."
backslash_cat = "I'm \\ a \\ cat."

fat_cat = """
I'll do a list
\t* Cat food
\t* Fishies
\t* Catnip\n\t* Grass
"""

print(tabby_cat)
print(persian_cat)
print(backslash_cat)
print(fat_cat)

"""
```

Are there any alternative methods to ensure this code block is commented out?

Comment: You could use `'''` instead of `"""`

Comment: What kind of text editor or IDE are you using? Some of them have keyboard shortcuts that comment out multiple lines by prepending them with `#`. For example, in Notepad++ it's ctrl-K.

Comment: As suggested by @Kevin, try commenting out the block by prefixing each line with `#`. This is a very common editor feature. You could also consider removing the code in a version control system. Other workarounds will likely fail in this or a similar manner (for example you could use `'''`, but a section could use both `'''` and `"""`, foiling this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show the problem by an arrow in your code:

```
"""

tabby_cat = "\tI'm tabbed in."
persian_cat = "I'm split\non a line."
backslash_cat = "I'm \\ a \\ cat."

fat_cat = """
I'll do a list
\t* Cat food
\t* Fishies
\t* Catnip\n\t* Grass
""" <-----------------------------------------DELETE THIS ONE OR ADD ANOTHER ONE

print(tabby_cat)
print(persian_cat)
print(backslash_cat)
print(fat_cat)

"""
```

Comment: Their problem is that they're trying to comment out *code* which contains a multiline string; presumably any original code shouldn't be modified!